Tomcat 7 embedded server run in Intellij idea with JSP source and target compiler version 1.8 not working
I am using Intellij IDEA 2022.1.4 as my IDE. I have a spring MVC java 1.8 application running on Tomcat version 7.0.109.
In my web.xml I have added the JSP servlet class and initialised the compiler source and target version to 1.8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

pom.xml looks as below.(only sharing information related to the issue)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.109</tomcat.version>
    <tomcat.port>8080</tomcat.port>
</properties>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
            <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
            <serverXml>${tomcat.serverXml}</serverXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
            <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

server.xml file changes,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector emptySessionPath="true" port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="1000" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="C:/work/" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" startStopThreads="0">
                <Context path="/dashboard" docBase="workspace/java-app/src/main/webapp" crossContext="true">...</Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>

DEV server: I have tomcat server(7.0.109) installed and over there the server.xml is configured accordingly. Using startup.sh, I bring the server up and also the same JSP gets compiled using Java 1.8 and no errors are seen. I ran the below command to verify the JSP class file version and it is 1.8 as expected.
javap -verbose report_jsp.class | grep "major version"
Output:52
Intellij local deployment: In my IDE I am using the embedded server and in the Run configuration I have the below command configured.
clean install tomcat7:run -Dtomcat.serverXml=../server.xml -DskipTests -Dspring.profiles.active=alpha
The server comes up fine and I am able to access the application as well. But when I access any JSP file, I expect it to be compiled using Java version 1.8 but it does not seem to work that way. I see the below warning and error.
Warning:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler generateClass  WARNING: Unknown source VM 1.8 ignored.
Error:
List<Map<String, String>> reports=new ArrayList<>();
An error occurred at line: 341 in the jsp file: /admin/report.jsp
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
The above error definitely indicates that the tomcat server is still compiling the JSP using version 1.6 and not picking changes from the web.xml. If anyone has faced issues with the same, please suggest any workaround or solution if any. I tried using "additionalClasspathDirs" in the plugin configuration and referenced a custom folder in which I kept all the jars that are part of tomcat server lib folder, but still no luck.
PS: I prefer to use the tomcat7:run for my local development work and would prefer to use this approach to bring my local tomcat server up.

I have in the pipeline to upgrade to Tomcat 9, but for now, I would appreciate a solution my Tomcat 7 with Java 8 works with my IntelliJ IDEA with the maven tomcat7:run command.
